# Python: Printing Unicode to File

Tags: python, unicode

```
   file = open('unicode.txt', 'wb')

    for i in range(10):
        file.write(str(unichr(i) ))
```

What i would like to do is to print all of the Unicode values to a text file

Comment: Did you forget the 'b' on 'wb'?  Is that the question?  If so, please revise this to (1) format code properly and (2) actually ask an actual question so we know what problem you're actually having.

Comment: "Unicode values"?  Do you mean "characters" or "bytes"?  A unicode character requires one or more bytes depending on the encoding.  What do you want to do with this file?

Answer (score 2):

```
somefile = codecs.open('unicode.txt', 'wb', someencoding)

for i in range(10):
    somefile.write(unichr(i))
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need the `str()` call around `unichr(i)`. Python `unicode` objects are printable.

This:

```
file = open('unicode.txt', 'wb')
for i in range(10):
    file.write(unichr(i))
```

Seems to work for me, it prints 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, etc. to the text file.

Comment: -1 `str()` is both unneeded AND unwanted. Using it will guarantee FAILURE for i >= 256. "Python unicode objects are printable " -- sometimes, depending on which objects, what platform, narrow/wide-unicode Python build, default encodings, fonts available, Python 2.x or 3.x, phase of moon, etc. On my set-up your code produces a 10-BYTE file containing `'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t'` ... If i == 128, the outcome for me is `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`